# Skip Iteration Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a very simple For Loop in Google Apps Script to check some conditions in a Google Sheet. What I want is to add another condition, if it is met, then I want to skip current iteration and move on to next. This is pretty easy in VBA, but I am not sure how to do it on JavaScript.

Current code:

```
for (var i=1 ; i<=LR ; i++)
    {
     if (Val4 == "Yes")
      {
       // Skip current iteration...   <-- This is the bit I am not sure how to do
      }
     elseif (Val1 == "Accepted" && !(Val2 == "") && !(Val3 == ""))
      {
        // Do something..
       }
      else
      {
       // Do something else...
      }

    }
```

Comment: Read about loop control statements in JavaScript. Namely, `break` and `continue`. Note that if your for loop has only a single logical statement (your if-else if chain), then simply adding that check and using an empty conditional body will suffice.

Comment: you probably mean continue statement https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_break.asp. If not, then showing the VBA alternative should make the question clear

Comment: @Slai - thanks for that. Really useful. Please put that in answer and I will mark as correct.

Comment: This question was solved with a minimum of research. An internet search with generic keywords should have led you to the answer - part of [asking a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Did you do any research before asking?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`continue` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue) can be used to continue to next itteration :

```
for (var i=1 ; i<=LR ; i++)
{
  if (Val4 == "Yes")
  {
    continue; // Skip current iteration... 
  }
  // Do something else...
}
```

---

In your sample case, leaving the if block empty will achieve the same result:

```
for (var i=1; i <= LR; i++)
{
  if (Val4 == "Yes")
  {

  }
  elseif (Val1 == "Accepted" && !(Val2 == "") && !(Val3 == ""))
  {
    // Do something..
  }
  else
  {
    // Do something else...
  }
}
```